# Chaining Null-Safe Operator

Tags: groovy, nullpointerexception

My project has code like the following:

```
params.stringValue?.trim().replaceAll('aa', 'a')
```

We expected that if `params.stringValue` was null, that **both** `trim()` and `replaceAll()` would not be called.

However we were getting a `NullPointerException` on this line saying that `replaceAll()` cannot be called on a null Object.

We had to change the code to be like this:

```
params.stringValue?.trim()?.replaceAll('aa', 'a')
```

Why does the first code snippet above not work?  Is this a bug in Groovy that it continues to evaluate the expression after a null has been encountered once?

Comment: I think it's a "feature", rather than a bug(!)

Comment: another gotcha is code like priceItemInstance?.activePriceItemDelta?.pricePerUnitList[i] you need to replace with priceItemInstance?.activePriceItemDelta?.pricePerUnitList?.getAt(i) to be null safe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the way Groovy works, indeed, and has bitten [others](https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/groovys-safe-navigation-operat):

> println book?.author?.firstName?.trim().concat(" is great.")
>
> ...
>
> Looking at this line of code, I thought for sure I was safe from any sneaky NullPointerException. If book, author or firstName are null I'll simply end up printing null and not have to worry about the concat() method. After all, if the trim() method succeeds, there's no sense in guarding it's result for null. And that's where I was wrong.

There have been at least [this discussion](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.groovy.user/58638/match=null+safe+navigation) to change that:

> a?.b.c    // Do you see the error? ;)
>
> I will get a NullPointerException. I mean, if you use the null-safe ?. operator in a chained expression,
> you have to use in all properties because if you forget to put in somewhere, you will get an error too. It will
> be nice if Groovy could detect the ?. operator in an expression, and it injects it in the other properties if
> it sees the operator is missing. So, if you would type this
>
> a?.b?.e.f?.g     // I forget to put the ?. .n the "f" property
> a?.b.e.f.g
>
> Groovy could fix it with a real null-safe expression like this:
>
> a?.b?.e?.f?.g

Answer (score 15):

I don't think your assumption was correct. this:

```
params.stringValue?.trim().replaceAll('aa', 'a')
```

does not mean:

```
if(params.stringValue is null)
   dont proceed to trim() and replaceAll()
```

It rather means:

```
if(params.stringValue is null)
   skip trim() without complain but pass null to replaceAll()
```

so you need to say:

```
params.stringValue?.trim()?.replaceAll('aa', 'a')
```

This will skip both `trim()` and `replaceAll()` if the incoming argument is null.

Answer (score 9):

Your assumption is only partially correct.

The `?`-operator doesn't break the execution in case of null, it blocks calling the current method, and returns a `null` instead, which is why it's necessary also to protect the right-hand side of the chain with `?`